# Send a tweet in symfony2's HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: hwioauthbundle

I want when a user registers using twitter, to tweet automatically on his account a message. 
Can I do it through HWIOAuthBundle.
I can't find anything on Google , is this even possible ?

 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I searched for same thing, there is nothing much, using Guzzle as service seemed to me as best solution. I'm not sure if you have to have bundle beside Guzzle lib to use it, best search pops this bundle https://github.com/ddeboer/GuzzleBundle abandoned 2 years ago. I guess whole Symfony framework is not that alive as it used to be. I considered switching to Laravel for calling Twitter Api, this lib pops up https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4 but those static ::methods look not much useful to me, it should be done as service. I wanted to  use framework module to call Api, but simple including twitteroauth lib makes more sense.

If you manage do call Guzzle as service in Symfony please share how you did it.

Comment: You know what I did? 
I separated the abraham library on my server and executed the php script in a command line